# How to re-assign a ref hook

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I'm implementing an infinite scroll feature using the `IntersectionObserver` api. I'm using the useRef hook to target certain elements.
`let ref = useRef()` and I need to reassign the ref to target a new element when the new content loads. Right now reassigning the ref give 2 or more elements the same ref. How can I safely change the ref to the new element and remove the old one.

**EDIT**

Re-assigning
`items[index].ref = ref`

Comment: Can you show the code and/or snippet of how you are assigning the ref?

Comment: You can't. Assuming that both components will keep mounted. Use 2 `refs` and toggle between the selected one.

Comment: _"need to reassign"_ Is the reassignment for the element you are using for the IntersectionObserver? If so why not just keep the same element with the same ref and just continually move to the bottom of the content on load of more content?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes the reassignment is to change what the observer is looking at. If there is no content I need to call the api or trigger some error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to get around this issue is to flip the logic. Assign the ref to the observer. That way the ref does not change and you can use the functionality of the Intersection observer (connect & disconnect) to point to different DOM elements.

More Reading: https://www.darrencoxall.com/react/intersection-observer-component/